# How to enable CORS for API Gateway for Rest API using Proxy integration

Tags: amazon-web-services

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'some url' from origin 'origin url' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

In the API Gateway console you can enable CORS:

[image]

Brings you to

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in case you use type of LAMDA for integretion

- enable poxy integretion from Lamda here

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcvo0.png)